# WS in TIBCO BW or in Java

Tags: java, jms, tibco, eai, businessworks

I see it is a lot faster developing a WS in TIBCO compared to coding in Java.

Is it wise investment to use TIBCO as your WS Service Provider & Service Requester?

Also both previous question for developing a JMS consumer & publisher.

How would my Server-side Java code use/listen to the BW Process? So far I read about TIBCO Adapters to do that with a lot of features like monitoring, but would this be just an overhead? Is it better to just code your WS & JMS codes in your Java app?

How do you decide if you would implement a functionality in Java or in TIBCO (e.g. send a Mail, Logging, etc.)?

Thanks a lot! 
Thirdy

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using TIBCO Business Works to implement your SOAP Web Services and to invoke SOAP Web Services will certainly save you a lot of time compared to creating them in Java.

Whether it's a "wise investment" really depends on the amount of development your doing. The TIBCO BW licenses are not cheap, but with a large development team and a large body of development work, you can get a return on investment very quickly. If you've got just one project and only a couple of developers, you might not see a return on investment (i.e., the license cost could be more than the cost of developing the project in Java).

Your Server-side Java code would use/listen to BW by simply invoking the web services. [Axis 2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/) will make your life easier in this regard.

In terms of deciding what you would develop in Java and what you would develop in TIBCO BW, I would answer everything you can in TIBCO BW, with some custom java where you need it. BW is Java based, so it's trivially easy to add Java code to any project.

Comment: thanks a lot Tom! great answer. I think I'll go with the Java solution. I'll go do my Java WS research now :)

Comment: @thirdy: in that case have a look at http://www.zienit.nl/blog/2010/01/rest/hateoas-by-example and http://www.infoq.com/articles/webber-rest-workflow for non-SOAP based web services